# Calculate the true pixel width of a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to calculate width in px for given text in span element. I check several answers in Stackoverflow. However nothing work for me :(. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LhvDr/). And here is code:

```
    $.fn.textWidth = function(){
      var html_org = $(this).html();
      var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
      $(html_calc).css('font-size', this.css('font-size'));
      $(this).html(html_calc);
      var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
      $(this).html(html_org);
      return width;
    };

    var ts_name = $('span#ts_name');
    var ts_name_text=ts_name.text().trim();
    var ts_name_p_box_width = $('div#container-testset-name').innerWidth()-100;
    var text_width = $(ts_name).textWidth();
```

My result for text_p_box_width is 737px and for text_width 715px. However it is clear from html view in Chrome browser text size is bigger than its container. SO what is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

> **P.S.** If you need some clarification please leave as comment.
>
> **Edit:** I saw similar answer of @LeeTaylor in other question. However it doesn't solve my problem. Because in my case text inside of span element. But in your case text inside of div. I can not change span's display property to block. So for my case this does not work. I tried to generate dynamically two elements using jQuery and try to fetch width. But it is 0. I found that since this dynamically created objects does not included to DOM tree and CSS not applied it will work.

```
`var ts_name=$('span#ts_name').text().trim();

        var text_container = $(document.createElement('span')).html(ts_name).attr('id', 'input_text');
        var block_container = $(document.createElement('div')).html(text_container).css({display:'block'});
        block_container.css({width: '3000px'});

        console.log($(block_container).find('span#input_text').width());
        console.log($(block_container).find('span#input_text').outerWidth());
        console.log($(block_container).find('span#input_text').innerWidth());
```

I did because I want to use your solution however it does not work. So do you have any idea on that?

> **SOLUTION:** I figure out why my code is not working I just change only one value in css like this:

```
div#ts_designer>div#container-testset-name.c-group-inner-row span#ts_name 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto!important;
    white-space: nowrap; /*This line added*/ 
}
```

Here is updated jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LhvDr/1/).

> **P.S.** I will up vote your answers as reward to your answers. However I cannot accept one of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: Eyal Alsheich I solve my problem by my self. It was tiny thing in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `scrollWidth`?

This might do what you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/eJMAD/

scrollWidth might not work the same across all browsers though, so maybe someone else has a better solution more cross-browser friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I use this utility function:

HTML:

```
<div>hello this is a test</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function()
{
    var old = $(this).html();
    $(this).html( $("<span>").html( $(this).html() ) );
    var width = $(this).find("span:first").width();
    $(this).html(old);
    return width;
};

alert("Width of the text in the div = " + $("div").textWidth());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ4e6/)

Comment: Interesting but I'd rather make a copy of `this` element and work on that. In your approach you can restore the HTML by stashing it in `old`, but that will create a totally new set of DOM elements, breaking some code that saved references to the previous ones, stripping out their event handlers etc.